# Search bar in main menu

Tags: 7, theming, routes, search

I would like to place the search bar in the main menu on the right. I have seen several people on the net asking for this but never encountered some information I could actually use.
I use Drupal 7 and the "Responsive Blog" by Devsaran.

As far as I understand the way to go is inserting some php into the main menu code in the main-menu part in page.tpl. This is what it looks like but I am struggeling with the exact to dos now...

```
<nav id="navigation" role="navigation">
  <div id="main-menu">
    <?php 
      if (module_exists('i18n_menu')) {
        $main_menu_tree = i18n_menu_translated_tree(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu'));
      } else {
        $main_menu_tree = menu_tree(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu'));
      }
      print drupal_render($main_menu_tree);
    ?>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach:

1. Start by adding a new region to the theme's .info file:

   regions[navigation] = Navigation
2. Next, *render* the region. Put the code below in page.tpl.php either just before or just after the </div> in your code above. You may need to experiment a little.

   <?php print render($page['navigation']); ?>
3. Clear your cache so your site knows that the new region exists.
4. Next, in Admin -> Structure -> Blocks, place the Search block in the Navigation region.
5. Finally, style the search form so it looks the way you want.

Comment: Remark for other readers: I had to insert it between <nav> and <div>:

 `<nav id="navigation" role="navigation">
  <?php print render($page['navigation']); ?>
 <div id="main-menu">`